# T-SQL query not grouping correctly

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have written this query to extract a count from a case statement, joined to a list of days. But the query isn't grouping correctly. Any idea what I need to do?

```
select      A.DayName,
        A.DayNumber,
        count(case
        when cast([B].ReturnedDateTime as Time) <= '12:00:00' then 1 else null
        end) as AMCount
from        TSP1_Dev.General.Days A left outer join TSP1_Dev.iOPS.RejectedJobs B
on          A.DayName = B.DayName
group by     A.DayName, A.DayNumber, 
        case
        when cast([B].ReturnedDateTime as Time) <= '12:00:00' then 1 else null
        end
order by     A.DayNumber
```

The output I get is this:

```
DayName DayNumber   AMCount
Monday  1   0
Monday  1   1
Tuesday 2   0
Tuesday 2   2
Wednesday   3   0
Thursday    4   0
Thursday    4   2
Friday  5   0
```

Comment: Whats is the initial problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select      A.DayName,
    Max(A.DayNumber) DayNumber,
    Sum(case
    when cast([B].ReturnedDateTime as Time) <= '12:00:00' then 1 else 0
    end) as AMCount
from        TSP1_Dev.General.Days A left outer join TSP1_Dev.iOPS.RejectedJobs B
on          A.DayName = B.DayName
group by     A.DayName
order by     A.DayNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I didn't need to group by the case statement - when I took that out it worked perfectly.